# Selective Drop Rights on Table possible?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to give a user selective drop rights in the database; preference is to use wildcards.

I have a database in which I could theoretically work with temporary tables without having the corresponding drop rights. But since it happened in the workflow, which is mostly already discarded when calling the temporary table, I thought about creating regular tables.

I don't want to give the user the possibility to delete the other tables when I unlock drop.

Is there a way, using wildcards or something similar, to crop the drop right, for example access query_* tables?

Comment: we need to know what dbms your are using to answer that. Is it PostgreSQL, SQLServer, MySQL ?

Comment: Removed distracting comments and verbiage.